# Table margin in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

How can I insert margin (top margin in my case) to table in MS Word 2013? The table is located at the top of the first page, but I can't resize the height of the header (because of the other pages) and I don't want to insert empty paragraph (the document to be typographically corrent). Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below two ways:

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, this will bring up the `Page Setup` dialog box, here you can adjust the `Top Margin`

   [image]
2. You can try inserting a Text Box of the same length above your Table which can act as the Header.

Comment: The text box will be possibly the best workaround in this case, because page margin will affect all pages.